# Where to put gitIgnore file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

I am developing an app and I must take that project to GitHub. Now, I must make gitIgnore file. I know that file is used to ignore some specified files from my project. I used gitIgnore.io service and I received generated file. This is my gitIgnore file:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/android

### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml

# Keystore files
*.jks

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs
```

But I don't know were to copy this, and where to put that in my Android project.
Could someone help me?

I copied this file into my gitIgnore file in Android Studio, but when I have pushed that project on gitHub my gitnigore file looks like this:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

So, that files that I copied into Android Studio are not here. What is the problem?

Answer (score 32):

Normally when creating a new project the gitignore file is generated for you.

Here is the correct .gitignore file.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

This is were you have to put it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. Just another question: What do you think, is gitignore.io service is good enough for making .gitignore files? Other words, is all that I need to ignore is generated here?

Comment: The Android Studio is generating the gitignore every time you create a new project. If you are working on an existing project copy and paste the text above. You don't need anything else. gitignore.io is awesome but you don't need it.

Comment: But how about the `build` folder in 'app' module?!

Comment: But the project can have modules for other platforms, eg. google app engine, so putting the .gitignore in root of project mean that you have your Android .gitignore rules applying to non-Android code (and vica-versa since you'd need to pile the rules for all modules into 1 file).

Comment: anybody know why there is also a separate gitignore in the 'app' directory?

Comment: I believe that's useful in large repos where each app is treated as a different git submodule.

Answer (score 10):

**.gitignore** file must be in the root directory of the project not just in android projects but in any project types

I hope my answer would be useful

Comment: Well I had bad explained my problem. When I download this file from gitIgnore service what exactly should I do after that?

Comment: just copy the content of file and make file in project root called .gitigniore in project root and git will ignore any file that match the expressions in this file

Comment: I copied this file next to gradle files in my project end when I wanted to rename it to the ".gitignore" then I receive this message "The name “.gitignore” is already used in this location. Please use a different name."

Comment: the git .gitignore is a hidden file just show hidden files in your system and edit the file by copying the content generated from gitignore.io to the file

Comment: I found that file and overwrite it but when i posted project on gitHub my gitignore file looks like this:
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures Is that means that file which I downloaded it did not copied well or what?

Comment: I think it would be better if you make each entry in separate line

Answer (score 7):

**Location**
The file should always be placed in the root directory of the project.

**Contents**
Check out [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) handy page on Github with template gitignore files for Android and other languages - they represent best practice and are regularly updated.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.