# Android Studio .ignore plugin. Proper destination for gitignore file

Tags: android, android-studio, gitignore

I use .ignore plugin to create my gitignore file.

When I select .gitignore file, then this window shows up.

[image: Choose Destination Directory]

My question is rather simple. What is the proper destination for gitignore file? Is there any rule? Or maybe it's totally up to me?

Comment: I think you can refer to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219957/where-to-put-gitignore-file-in-android-studio